# How to filter Firebase data in Swift from another parent?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

*Original: I have run into something I can not figure out: 
I have a list of customers with their data, and I have a list over calendar dates where the customers are marked available in Firebase. And I need to figure out how I can exclude customer based on the calendar.
I have searched around, and found this question that almost answers my question:*

UPDATED: I now have changed my Firebase Database to not have to separate parents, but include it in customers

[How to filter Firebase data in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647742/how-to-filter-firebase-data-in-swift)

```
        // This is my new code from the link above
        ref.child("customers").queryOrdered(byChild: "calendar").
        queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in


        let snapshotDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            let name = snapshotDict?["Name"] as! String
            let email = snapshotDict?["Email"] as! String
            let rating = snapshotDict?["Rating"] as! String
            let key = snapshot.key

            self.posts.insert(postStruct(name: name, email: email, rating: rating, key: key), at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
```

So if I should only check if the value of "calendar" = true, this would have worked. But I have several keys and values in calendar, and I don't know the next step for this. My database looks like this:

```
    customers:
      - sk1239sdkq2312lk
            - calendar
                  - 9. june, 2018
                       - 1 : 10:00    
      - lk3j4590gsdflkj2
            - calendar
                  - 9. june, 2018
                       - 1 : 10:00    
      - x98123jasdhasdss
            - calendar
                  - 9. june, 2018
                       - 3 : 12:00
```

And I only want to insert the two first customers who have 9. June, 2018 and 1 : 10:00 in my table.

*I have the date (9. June, 2018) and time (10:00) I'm looking for, but not the number (1, 2, 3).*

How can I do this?

Comment: Please include your Firebase structure snippet as TEXT please, no links or images. If the link breaks, it would invalidate your question. Most importantly, when someone answers they may need to include your structure and we really don't like having to retype all of that. If it's text, we can copy and paste. Take a look at [Linked Images Are Evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Thanks! I do not have any code for this issue, other than the code in the similar question mentioned. I'll guess some of the code is similar. 

Someone helped me to change the images from linked to embedded, and they are there to show how my database is organised.

Comment: Again, please *do NOT include links or images* we text. As you can see, if I had an answer that included your Firebase structure, it would have to be retyped. To get a snippet of your structure use the Firebase Console->Export JSON, open the text file and copy and paste a snippet of the TEXT into the question.

Comment: Also, based on your structure, you won't be able to get what you want so it will need to be changed. Lastly, please don't use array's - they really don't lend themselves to NoSQL databases well. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179477/firebase-changing-layout-of-child-data-information-in-android/43191862#43191862) and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166876/how-do-i-design-a-simple-firebase-database-that-stores-arrays/42170435#42170435)

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, I have now updated my question and code, and removed all the images.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Realtime Database nor Cloud Firestore support single query on multiple collections (or subcollections) .

You can either hold a reference to the calendar collection and query against it on the client side, after retrieving **all** customers. This has obvious drawbacks.

The other option is to include a field inside the `Customer` model (e.g. `usedCalendar`) defaulted to false and then use Firebase [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions) to keep that field value consistent. You'd add the `onCreate()` and `onDelete()` hooks to the `calendar` collection and update the appropriate customer's `usedCalendar` value.

Comment: Thanks you so much for this. I have now updated my question as I have changed the way I use my database..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to boil down to getting your database architected properly. Once that's done, it should be easy. First, use Firestore unless there is a solid reason not to. ...Assuming you can use Firestore, seems like you would have a (fairly standard) root level `users` collection where each `user` has a (sub)collection called `operating` full of docs with `uid`'s. Each doc has a property called `activity` which chould be "meeting" or "vacation" or "busy", etc.

I'm doing something similar for storing my users shipping locations.

[Firestore supports compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) so, filling out your calendar should be rather easy.

[image]

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can not change my database to Firestone right now. But I have changed the way I have managed the Realtime Database now as you see in my edited post. I will look into Firestone in the future.

Comment: Do you have another method for me for this question?