# Snapshot value from Firebase is nil in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app in which I am trying to get an array of all of the values at a certain location in my realtime database (using firebase). My code does not execute because "let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]" is nil. Why is it nil? My code:

```
func likeToLikeForAll() {
    let uid  = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("Liked Movies").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let array = Array(dictionary.keys)
        }
    })
}
```

Image: [image]

Comment: Let's start with the obvious: Is there data in that node? can you post your firebase schema?

Comment: @Simon There is data there, I updated the question with a photo of the location I am trying to reach

Comment: The issue may be that your keys are `Int` values and you are trying to cast it as a `String`. Try changing it to `as? [Int: Bool]` and see if that works.

Comment: @Simon That doesn't seem to work. I believe the numbers are actually ints (because they are only names), but they contain bools

Comment: Ah taking a closer look the `observeSingleEvent` returns all the values from the child uid node. So the snapshot value is actually an array of dictionaries I believe. Try this: 

```if let dictionaryArray = snapshot.value as? [[Int: Bool]] {
           print(dictionaryArray)
    }```

Comment: @Simon Nothing is printed. dictionaryArray is set to nil

Comment: What happens when you just print out `snapshot.value` without the if statement inside your closure?

Comment: @Simon This is printed: Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x60400024a830>(
<null>,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1
)
)

Comment: From there, it just prints out the bool values. You can't cast an array of bool values into a dictionary. Try printing out `snapshot.key`. I'm not too familiar with firebase or how you set up those keys. What I did was I explicitly create the keys with a random string instead of having it auto incremented like yours. Maybe the auto generated keys prevent you from accessing the whole somehow? I'm not sure...

Comment: @Simon Okay, I think I should be able to figure it out from here. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The main problem here is storing Firebase data in an array. It's best practice to avoid arrays in NoSQL databases as they are highly inflexible. There are usually much better ways to store data (childByAutoId being one). I don't know the use case but you may want to re-think your structure. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166876/how-do-i-design-a-simple-firebase-database-that-stores-arrays/42170435#42170435) for further reading if you are interested.