# How to make firebase list like this on swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**This is what I want it to be**

[image]

first I did it like this:

```
self.ref.child("User/CareGiver/\(CaregiverUID)/Followed").setValue([value2])
```

the result looks like in the picture. but when I add second data. It replaces the old one.

so I change to this

```
self.ref.child("User/CareGiver/\(CaregiverUID)").updateChildValues([
            "Followed" : ["\(value2)"]])
```

it still replaces data at position[0] and never make it to position [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ4wG.png)
how can I do 
array [UID1,UID2,UID3] to firebase (not add array data at the same time so it would be like this)

```
-[0] UID1
-[1] UID2
-[2] UID3
```

without replacing another one?

ps.sorry for broken English

JSON should look likes this

```
{
  "Name_Care" : "asdsท",
  "Tel_Care" : "kknlk",
  "Role" : "Care Giver",
  "Followed" : [
    "UID_A",
    "UID_B",
    "UID_C",
    "UID_E"
  ]
}
```

in firebase would be like in picture

Comment: You are *really* not going to want to use arrays for this. Arrays don't work well in NoSQL databases as they are essentially a single object - changing them required deleting the array and re-writing it - there are usually much better options. See [Arrays are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179477/firebase-changing-layout-of-child-data-information-in-android/43191862#43191862) and [Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166876/how-do-i-design-a-simple-firebase-database-that-stores-arrays/42170435#42170435) for some more reading.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to add new values to your "followed" dictionary, you should use "setValue" function with uniq id for your new user.
Example:
`self.ref.child("User/CareGiver/\(CaregiverUID)/Followed").setValue("3":"user_name")`
In this case you add record `user_name` for key `3`

I think this way can help you.

Comment: I already did that. but what if i add new one UID.I would have to change to [4] myself. I want it as array object but firebase don't support array

Comment: So, if you want to modify record with key 4, you should use `self.ref.child("User/CareGiver/\(CaregiverUID)/Followed"). updateChildValues(["4":"<new_user_name>"])`

In my opinion, you should add new followed users something like that:
`self.ref.child("User/CareGiver/\(CaregiverUID)/Followed"). updateChildValues(["userID":"<user_name>"])`

Also, when you get dict from db, you can get all data from it, like you work with simple array

Comment: I want it to look like Json code above. other then when i try to decode  it keeps saying "expected to decode array<any> but found a dictionary instead." but when i change struct dictionary. "expected to decode dictionary<string, any> but found a string/data instead."