# .childAdded with queryLimited duplicating data when .childMoved was only suppose to be triggered

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**EDIT**

The `addChatDataListener()` gets **only** 3 results from the users-chat data based on timestamp and `addChatChangedListener()` listens for any data that changed based on timestamp. Lets say there are 5 chats 1,2,3,4,5 and it gets 1,2,3 based on timestamp so these results are now on the client side or in the array. When i manually update the chatID 3 timestamp to be the latest in the DB from the firebase console. Only .childMoved was fired But when i change chatID 4 (which was not grabbed). Both .childMoved and .childAdded are fired duplicating data.

```
var tableView = UITableView()
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var chats = [Chat]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.frame = self.view.frame
    tableView.register(ChatTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "chatCell")
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    addChatDataListener()
    addChatChangeListener()
}

func addChatDataListener(){
    (ref.child("user_chats").child(myUsername)).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: 3).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
        let chat = self.getChatObject(snapshot: snapshot)
        print("child added: \(chat)")
        self.chats.insert(chat, at: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    })
}
func addChatChangeListener(){
    (ref.child("user_chats").child(myUsername)).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observe(.childMoved, with: {(snapshot) in
        let index = self.indexOfChat(key: snapshot.key)
        let chat = self.getChatObject(snapshot: snapshot)
        print("child moved: \(index)")
        print("child moved: \(chat)")
        if(index == -1){
            self.chats.insert(chat, at: 0)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        }else{
            self.chats[index] = chat
            let chat = self.chats.remove(at: index)
            self.chats.insert(chat, at: 0)
            self.tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
        }
           })
}
```

[image: This is my database]

Comment: I am not sure what appears to be going on is actually going on. .childAdded is strict and will fire once for each child when first attached and then **only** when a child is added after that. If a timestamp is changed the .childMoved event will fire. My guess is that a new node is actually created elsewhere in your code instead of updating an existing one and it's being overwritten so it appears like both events are firing; one when the timestamp is changed and one when a new node is added, overwriting the old one. Can you include the code that adds or updates your Firebase?

Comment: Hey i added more explanation. I was updating the entity manually from the firebase realtime database. just changing the timestamp. When i changed the entity that was already grabbed on the client side. Only .childMoved was fired but when it was an entity that was not grabbed on the client side both .childMoved and .childAdded were fired

Comment: The added code doesn't tell us anything. We don't need to know what functions you're calling - we need to know what the code is that's dealing with these changes. Like this *But when 3 which was already on client side* what does 'already on client side' mean? How is it already on client side? When there's a change are you updating an array or something else? Changing the value of a child node in Firebase will *never* fire a child added event so there's either some misunderstanding of what the issue is or how it's be described. How are you manually updating the entity?

Comment: Also, if you receive events with updated objects, keep in mind those objects already exist in your array (assuming you're using an array) so those need to be updated instead of adding onto the array. We really need to see more code - Please review the following guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i updated my question, By manually i mean i'm updating the database from the firebase console. And by 3 i mean the .queryLimited(3) so it would only get three latest results but when i update something that was not in the .querylimited(3) it will fire .childAdded() as well

Comment: i added a screenshot of my database. That is where im manually changing it .

Comment: I gotcha - answer provided. Also, please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using an array - they cannot be re-ordered and are very challenging to use in a NoSQL database as the elements cannot be changed within the scope of the array. There are usually (almost always) much better options for structuring and storing your data.

In brief, an array in code can have an index removed and the object at the following index 'moves up' and fills that spot. Likewise, objects can be inserted in an array and the following elements 'move down'.

Array's in Firebase do not work that way; to make changes in the order, count etc, the entire array has to be read in updated and then written back out - hence the multiple events firing as mentioned in my comments.

See this dated but on point blog [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and some further reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166876/how-do-i-design-a-simple-firebase-database-that-stores-arrays/42170435#42170435)

You should change your structure;

```
user_chats
    uid_0
       random_chat_id_0 //created with .childByAutoId
           timestamp: 20191020
           unread_messags: 3
           user_id: uid_1  //don't use -> user_name: "some username"
       random_chat_id_1
           timestamp: 20191021
           unread_messags: 3
           user_id: uid_4
```

.childByAutoId is your friend and I generally recommend using it to create any kind of node key that must be unique.

Another suggestion is to avoid usernames; use the users uid. Usernames are often dynamic but user id's are static and tied that that specific user.

Last thing; the function `addChatChangeListener` is not that. There are two different query observers `.childChanged` and `.childMoved` and their function is very different. I would suggest renaming the function to `addChatMovedLister` to avoid confusion or change the code within the function to actually handle `.childChanged` events.